# Connect NServiceBus with an AIX Mainframe

Tags: nservicebus

I have a back end system that drops events to my system.  It is critical that these events don't get lost (I work for a health care company and lost info can impact a patient's care).

I would like to make this system drop it's data into NServiceBus so that it can be published to subscribers that need it.  However, my server that is dropping these messages is an AIX machine, so it can't run .NET Code.

This system can send the messages via a lot of standard protocol and communication types (TCP, WSDL Based Services, Call A Database Sproc, etc).

One option I have considered is to setup a WCF service that the AIX mainframe will call.  I can then have my WCF service make the call to NServiceBus.

But the events sent per minute of this back end service can at times be fairly high (about 500 messages per minute).  I am worried that WCF is not up to this, while NService bus says it can handle 1000 messages per second.  Am also worried about data loss in the event of a downtime.  NserviceBus claims it is not going to loose any data.

Am I wrong?  Is WCF going to be just fine?  Or am I making a weak link in the chain?

Is there a way I can use an established protocol to add items directly to an NServiceBus Queue?

Or should I just write my own .NET app that will allow NServiceBus to use a TCP connection?

**Note:** Because these messages are critical, the message must be acknowledged or the server will keep sending it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the WCF integration that comes right out of the box.  The WCF service is contained within the same host as NSB.  The integration does nothing more than just push the message onto the queue, so I don't think you'll have a throughput issue.  Seeing that this is critical data, I would suggest clustering the service.  The other option would be to install 2 or more instances of the service on different machines and load balance the HTTP calls across both.  In essence you would have 1 logical Publisher with 2 physical components doing the publishing.